# Finding a Closed Form of a Two Dimensional Recurrence

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In a problem I'm working on, the following two-index sequence keeps popping up:

$a(1,m) = 1$ for all $m$.

$a(n,m) = 1$ if $n = m$.

$a(n,m) = n(a(n,m-1) + a(n-1,m-1))$, $1 < n < m$.

And if $n > m$, $a(n,m)$ is not needed to be defined.

The sequence is almost like a messed-up Pascal's triangle. I would like to have a closed form relation for this sequence. I've tried messing around with 2D generating functions, but the results become messy very quickly.

Any help or hints would be appreciated!

EDIT: If anyone is interested in the math problem I'm working on, I am interested in finding a closed form of the sum $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{n^pr^n},$$
For all $p\in\mathbb{N}$ and with $|r|<1$. So far, I've proven that the following relation holds:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{n^pr^n}=\frac{1}{(1-r)^{p+1}}\sum_{k=1}^{p}{a(k,p)(1-r)^{p-k}},$$
Where $a(k,p)$ is the sequence in question. Thus, you can see why finding a closed form for this sequence could be of some interest. Perhaps knowledge of the problem can help solve the enigma.

(NOTE: I'm a high school senior, so if there is already a closed-form for this sum that I just haven't seen due to lack of exposure, I'd love to see it!)

Comment: Is the intent for $a_{n,m}$ with $n \ge m$? Otherwise it seems $a_{2,1} = -1/2$? In other words, if you don't want to define it for $n > m$, the first initial condition only gives $a_{1,1}$, no?

Answer (score 0):

At least the first couple of rows seem computable:
$$a_{1,m} \equiv 1 \forall m$$
and for the second row one can see
$$a_{2,m} = 3 \cdot 2^{m-2} - 2$$
and for the third row
$$a_{3,m} = 16 \cdot 3^{m-3} - 9 \cdot 2^{m-2} + 3$$
and because of the propagation rule, it seems plausible that you get
$$a_{n,m} = \sum_{k=1}^n c_{n,k} k^n$$
for some constants $\{c_{n,k}\}$...